# Spring MVC + Hibernate + one to one mapping : null pointer exception while session.save

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Problem Definition:

USER_TABLE and USER_DETAIL_TABLE are OneToOne mapped with userid field.
Facing two problems!

1. encounter nullpointer exception while saving UserDetailTable.

   - first setting UserTable and then saving USerDetailTable.
2. userid value is generated as 0, though i use nullable=false. 
   -Also sometime i see userid value for USER_TABLE is 1 and userid for USER_DETAIL_TABLE is 0. specially when i have already inserted one row for 'admin' while creating the tables.
3. I want to have default 'admin'  userid to be inserted while creating the database.

I am using the layout given by following site
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/

Using AppInitializer, AppConfig and Hibernate configuration from above example.

I update AppConfig to include tiles, and jsp pages, with two viewresolvers with one and two ordering respectively.

To keep things short, giving code snippets

User.Class

```
         @Entity
    @Table(name="USER_TABLE")

    public class User{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="userid", nullable=false)
        private int userid;
   ... 
...
    }
```

UserDetail.Class

```
 @Entity @Table(name="USER_DETAIL_TABLE")
public class UserDetail {

    //@Id
    @Column(name="userid", nullable=false)
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "genuserid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "genuserid", strategy="foreign", parameters =  @Parameter(value="USER_TABLE", name = "property") )
    private int userid;


    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;


    //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    private User user;


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

UserDetailDao Class

```
@Repository("UserDetailDao")
public class UserDetailDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements UserDetailDao {


    @Override
    public void saveUserDetail( UserDetail userdetail, User user) {
            // some time  userdetail.userid is 0!!
            //  and user.userid is 1 !!

        // setting User table info
        userdetail.setUser(user);

        //persist(userdetail);

        //getSession().beginTransaction(
        getSession().save(userdetail);
        //getSession().getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

UserDetailService Class

```
@Service("userdetailService")
@Transactional
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements  UserDetailService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailDao userDetailDao;

    @Override
    public void saveUserDetail(UserDetail userdetail,User user) {

        userDetailDao.saveUserDetail(userdetail, user);
    }
```

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class WebMainController {


    @Autowired
    UserDetailService userDetailService;

 //For add and update person both
        @RequestMapping(value= "useradd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addPerson(
  @ModelAttribute("userdetail") UserDetail userdetail,BindingResult resultUser,
  @ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult resultUserdetail
                                )
       {

                //UserDetail userdetail = new UserDetail();
                //userdetail.setUser(user);
                userDetailService.saveUserDetail(userdetail, user);

            return "redirect:/useradd";
        }
```

Using MySQL: SQL script

```
CREATE  TABLE user_table (
  userid INT(10) not null auto_increment, 
  loginname VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE  TABLE user_detail_table(
  userid INT(10) not null, 
  firstname VARCHAR(16)  ,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid),
   FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user_table (userid) 
   ON UPDATE CASCADE 
   ON DELETE CASCADE

  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO user_table(userid, loginname,password) VALUES (1,'admin','admin');
INSERT INTO user_detail_table(userid, firstname) VALUES (1,'Administrator');
```

one more Question

4. Can i manually insert a row in 'user' and 'user_detail' table to have 'admin' field? The annotation @GeneratedValue check the Database and then increment (generate) a value for the userid, am i right?

exception error is as follows

```
message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:650)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4736)
    org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:96)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    com.cms.sweb.dao.UserDetailDaoImpl.saveUserDetail(UserDetailDaoImpl.java:49)
    com.cms.sweb.service.UserDetailServiceImpl.saveUserDetail(UserDetailServiceImpl.java:23)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.saveUserDetail(Unknown Source)
    com.cms.sweb.controller.WebMainController.addPerson(WebMainController.java:87)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.20 logs.
```

If i miss anything, let me know i will add it. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is in GenericGenerator Annotation.

```
 @GenericGenerator(name = "genuserid", strategy="foreign", parameters =  @Parameter(value="USER_TABLE", name = "property") )
```

the correct one is as below

```
 @GenericGenerator(name = "genuserid", strategy="foreign", parameters =  @Parameter(value="user", name = "property") )
```

The 'value' should be object where the foreign key is mapped to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem with the Ids of rows added on tables, so maybe you should add the row in the table `User_Table` at first and get it's Id and then add the new row in the tabel `User_Detail_Table` with Id of the new row added in the first table, I have the same issue and I am thinking about the solution, try it and tell me if it works fine

Comment: Hibernate should take care of it right? hibernate simplifies in saving (inserting) data in two tables which is mapped together. if i have to take the id from User_Table and insert the row in User_detail_Table,  then what is use in doing OneToOne mapping?!!

Comment: it's right ! the database take care of id if this id is primary key and auto increment, but in the case of the relation one to one, the id of `User_detail_Table` is foreign key, so you have to get it from another table, with hibernate every thing is easy, try to read this explanation in this link maybe will help you [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/15/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-using-annotations/)

Comment: Gone through the link, but no information about Id value generation. annotation  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) in User_Table make sure value is generated automatically. 
    @GenericGenerator(name = "genuserid", strategy="foreign", parameters =  @Parameter(value="USER_TABLE", name = "property") )
    this annotation make sure it take value from USER_TABLE for USER_DETAIL TABLE. both primary key in both table are mapped. not convinced in getting id on one table and save it another with OneToOne mapping annotaton

Comment: I think thant the same solution with @GeneratedValue, check this link also [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: Does getting value from User_Table and inserting row in User_Detail_table mean using set operation?  usng stock.setStockDetail(stockDetail);
stockDetail.setStock(stock);  before session.save ?

Comment: in insert query , the fields are changed, will that be a problem?  the query should have userid, loginname,password,enabled, ssn, but is shows as follows :       insert  into user_table  (enabled, loginname, password, ssn)  values (?, ?, ?, ?)  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/sweb] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerExc

Comment: it's simple, just try what i gave to you at first you have to make a new instance of User() and add its information and then make a new instance of UserDetail and add  its information, after that you have to add the object Userdetail to the User object: 
`User user = new User();
//add informations by Set
UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail();
//add informations by Set
user.setUserDetail(userDetail);
userDetail.setUser(user);

session.save(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();`

i think that will work

Comment: I have already added those! but now i found the error is in GenericGenerator Annotation.  @GenericGenerator(name = "genuserid", strategy="foreign", parameters =  @Parameter(value="USER_TABLE", name = "property") )  the value should be 'user' object